# Windows 10 - any better way than Settings > Storage to remove system files

Tags: windows, windows-10, disk-space

I have searched and looked for "Windows 10 remove unnecessary files" with various search strings, especially from the System & Reserved files.  I have a 30G laptop and fully 13.8G are currently system and reserved files.  Everything regarding system files I've found revolves around going to Settings > Storage.

If there is NO WAY to get into that more fine-grained than that I'd be very surprised.  Clicking on it I get:

```
10.9 GB System Files
 2.47GB Virtual Memory
 392MB  Hibernation File
```

There is NO System Restore files, so that's not it.  Obviously I'd like to get into the 10.9GB and reduce that.

I have already deleted temp files, log files, and pared down display and animation of windows to zilch.  Performance improved but still facing problems with storage.  Is there any way to examine and safely pare down this 10.9GB of System Files?

-- **UPDATE/COMMENT** --

I have been able to remove the Hibernate file by this command line prompt:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>powercfg.exe -h off
```

which then shows as 0 bytes in Settings > Storage, which helps some.

Comment: Windows 10 has a 13GB+ requirement; There isn't any way to reduce it further

Answer (score 1):

In an administrator command prompt enter

COMPACT.EXE /CompactOS:always

From https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mniehaus/2015/09/16/windows-10-reducing-the-disk-footprint/

Saves 1-2GB

Comment: this saved about 1MB when I did it.  It may be that this particular piece was already optimized.  I think the comment on my post "There isn't any way to reduce it further" is unfortunately the best answer at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can clean temporary files by right clicking (properties) hard drive in windows explorer

Or... you can right click (properties) on hard and compress your files to make them more compact ;)